# Calling a method from another class - NSTextView not loading data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have 3 classes:

LocalRoom.m

```
- (void) handleNewConnection:(Connection*)connection {
    NSString* number = @"10";
    AppDelegate *theAppDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [theAppDelegate connectionNumber:number currentZoneName:@"Zone1";
}
```

**Triggers ----->**

AppDelegate.h

```
MyTableController *tableController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    tableController = [[MyTableController alloc] init];
}

- (void)connectionNumber:(NSString *)number zoneName:(NSString *)currentZoneName {
    if ([currentZoneName isEqualToString:zoneName1]) {
        [tableController changeConnections:number withRowNumber:0];
    }
}
```

**Triggers ----->**

MyTableController.h

```
@interface MyTableController : NSControl {
IBOutlet NSTextField *zoneNameTextField;  
}
@property (retain) NSTableView * idTableView;
- (void) changeConnections:(NSString *)number withRowNumber:(int)rowNumber;
```

MyTableController.m

```
- (void) changeConnections:(NSString *) number withRowNumber:(int) rowNumber{

    NSRunAlertPanel([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowNumber], number, @"", @"", @"");

    NSTableColumn *tableColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"Connections"];

    [self tableView:idTableView setObjectValue:number forTableColumn:tableColumn row:rowNumber];

    [idTableView reloadData];

}
```

My NSRunAlertPanel is coming up with the correct values, but my NSTextView is not changing. When I put the "edit" code for the NSTableView in an IBAction of MyTableController.m, it works. I checked if idTableView was NULL, and it was. Which is weird. So, I have a feeling something odd is happening when changeConnections is run by the AppDelegate. I had a similar problem with a nstextfield not returning data. The fix was to initialize it by `AppDelegate *theAppDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` Is there something similar in this case?

You might wonder why I'm just not calling MyTableController from LocalRoom, but "zoneName1" is set and found in the app delegate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At what point is handleNewConnection: being called? Without seeing that logic, I'm wondering if maybe it's happening before you nib is loaded... and I'm working under the assumption that your [MyTableController init] is calling [super initWithNibName:@"some nib" bundle:nilOrSomeBundle].

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown all the code, but `idTableView` is declared as a **@property** of `MyTableController`, but not as an **IBOutlet**.

That is `idTableView` being NULL strongly suggests that the `idTableView` property is never set to the appropriate table view. No `IBOutlet` for it means it can't be connected in the NIB/XIB. So the fix is probably to make it an outlet and connect it in the NIB.

Obviously, `[idTableView reloadData]` has no effect if `idTableView` is NULL.

I assume that your NIB does set `MyTableController` as its table data delegate, which is why the direct editing would work.

Further, although I don't think this is related to your problem, for best practice it doesn't make sense to manufacture a new `NSTableColumn` to work on your existing table -- you should be using `[idTableView tableColumnWithIdentifier: @"Connections"]` instead.

Comment: Hey! I'm sorry, I didn't include that. But 'IBOutlet NSTableView idTableView;' is there. It's odd why it's still returning null. I put the same code in the init of myTableController and it works.